# PHP Page doesn't display Stylesheets or Javascript when deployed to Web Service

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, google-app-engine

I am new to PHP. Just to get started with things, I created a new directory and copied some CSS and JS files I've been working on and created a PHP file and coped the HTML Code in to it.

**Directory**:

[image]

**Then I created a app.yaml file:**

```
application: project-test1234323
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: feed.php
```

**Header of the feed.php File:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Dashboard</title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Toastr style -->
    <link href="css/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Gritter -->
    <link href="js/plugins/gritter/jquery.gritter.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
```

**I deployed this to my Google App Engine Project (using Google App Engine Launcher for WIndows) and I end up with this:**

[image]

Why am I not seeing my style sheets or any of the web content for that matter. Have I configured the Directory wrong?

Comment: Check the `Network` tab in devtools and also check console for any errors

Comment: @Aziz Dang so many errors. Such as: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <feed.php:804... Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Right. You are using a `jQuery` plugin (jquery.gritter) without adding the core `jQuery` library... I'm also seeing a `SCSS` folder, are the `SCSS` files compiled?

Comment: Any idea why the CSS isn't getting referenced? @Aziz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because app engine doesn't know where to locate those files just yet. You'll need to make them known in your `app.yaml`'s handlers section:

You can write rules for all your static assets such as:

```
- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /font-awesome
  static_dir: fontawesome

- url: /fonts
  static_dir: fonts

- url: /img
  static_dir: img

- url: /js
  static_dir: js
```

etc, etc.

**To make things easier though**, you can move all your static resources into a new folder, and create a single handler to serve them all while properly referencing them in your main script

```
.
├── app.yaml
├── feed.php
└── static
    ├── css
    ├── font-awesome
    ├── fonts
    ├── img
    └── js
```

app.yaml:

```
url: /static
static_dir: static
```

feed.php:

```
<link href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
...
...
...
<link href="static/js/plugins/gritter/jquery.gritter.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

[Learn more about how to configure your php appengine app to respond to request handlers and static files here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig)